# How to display formatted text in Dialogflow using PHP Webhook

Tags: php, dialogflow-es

I need help, I have a list of items and they need to display nicely formatted in dialog flow for google assistant and Facebook.

For example:

1. Chair

2. Table

3. Desk lamp

4. Table

I am using the following code and also tried BR as well as Pre to format.

```
 foreach ($items as $value)
    {
        $itemname .= $value->id . ": " .$value->name ."\n";
   }  

     sendMessage(array(
        "source" => $update["result"]["source"],
        "speech" =>$itemname ,
        "displayText" => $itemname,
           "contextOut" => array()
          ));
```

The end result keeps on showing as 1. Chair 2. Table 3. Desk lamp 4. Table

Can anyone please help? I am unable to find the examples of how to list in dialog flow using php.

Comment: I don't think you need .=  try it without the .

Comment: That does not work.  I need to format it so that there is a line break after each item.